# mount ext4 disk: cannot mount /dev/sdc read-only

Tags: mount, ext4

I have an SSD disk with an `ext4` filesystem on it:

```
$ lsblk -f /dev/sdc 
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdc  ext4         142b28fd-c886-4182-892d-67fdc34b522a
```

I am attempting to mount it, but it is failing:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/data
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt/data
mount: /mnt/data: cannot mount /dev/sdc read-only.
```

- What does the error message mean?
- How can I diagnose and fix the problem?

To add additional information pertinent to an answer below:

There is only one partition on the disk.

Here is the result of executing `lsblk` for the boot disk:

```
$ lsblk /dev/sda
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   10G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  9.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0    4M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
```

and here is the result of executing `lsblk` for the disk in question:

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdc
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdc    8:32   0   2G  1 disk
```

Comment: @sourcejedi it is a 2GB SSD disk, in so far as it is a Google cloud storage drive being attached (read-only) to a GCE VM.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a USB thumb drive which was down to the ext4 journal recovery not working. `dmesg` confirmed this:

```
[1455125.992721] EXT4-fs (sdh1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[1455125.992725] EXT4-fs (sdh1): write access unavailable, cannot proceed (try mounting with noload)
```

As it suggested, mounting with noload worked:

```
sudo mount -o ro,noload /dev/sdh1 /mnt/drive
```

I was then able to backup the content:

```
sudo rsync -av /mnt/drive /data/tmp/
```

and then use `fdisk` to delete and recreate the  partition and then create a new filesystem with `mkfs.ext4`.

Comment: `noload` did it for me, thanks!

Comment: OMG, thank you!  I was able to mount the partition on a corrupted SD card and recover my files.

Comment: For me this did NOT work :-(. It's giving me out these errors in the CLI:
`wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`
and in dmesg;
`[46299.705185] loop0: detected capacity change from 0 to 7716864
[46299.706209] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'noload'
[46299.706241] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'noload'
[46299.706272] xfs: Unknown parameter 'noload'`
Please help! I really need to get some files back from my sd card.

Answer (score 4):

```
mount: /mnt/data: cannot mount /dev/sdc read-only.
```

The problem might be that the `ext4` filesystem on the device needs journal recovery, which is inherently a write operation. You might get more information by using the `dmesg` command after a mount attempt.

But I don't really see how your command

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt/data
```

was turned into a request for a read-only mount. Do you have an `/etc/fstab` line with specific options for this filesystem? Or do you have a custom script or alias named `mount` in root's environment?

Nevertheless, if the `dmesg` command does not provide any further insight, you might try an explicit request for a read-write mount:

```
sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdc /mnt/data
```

Or you might try running a filesystem check on it first:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -C0 /dev/sdc
```

Comment: lsblk shows the device is RO

Comment: Oh, so the device itself is reporting it's read-only for some reason! I did not notice that. That might indicate a hardware problem of some sort: use `sudo smartctl -HAf brief -l error /dev/sdc` for a health check, and try `sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdc /mnt/data` for at least a chance to get your data out from a possibly-failing SSD.

Comment: @telcoM the device is read-only. It is, in fact, a google cloud disk attached to a vm. I have previously mounted it read/write and populated it with data, which I now want to attach to a different VM read-only. Previously this has succeeded (with a warning saying it's mounting read-only, as I didn't provide `-ro`), so it seems perhaps your suggestion of journal recovery is correct? Although I managed to "fix" the problem by unattaching, reattaching it read-write, and then reattaching it read-only again, and then it worked! Perhaps a gcloud bug?

Answer (score 0):

If I read that correctly, you are trying to mount a non-partition. It could be a simple typo in that you should be using "/dev/sda1" or "/dev/sda2" etc.. instead of just "sda"

If that's not the case, you'll need to use a partitioning tool such as fdisk or gdisk (or a GUI based tool such as gparted) to create a partition table and a partition. Then install a filesystem in that partition using "mkfs".

Comment: `lsblk` shows that there is an `ext4` filesystem on the disk. There is only 1 partition, so `/dev/sdc` should be sufficient

Comment: Hmmm, I am unfamiliar if ext4 can use a raw block device without a partition table. This is a common thing with LVM2 and PV, so it may be doable.

Comment: @0xSheepdog: Yes, ext4 can do that. In fact, I think *any Linux filesystem driver* can do that.

Comment: I just followed the instructions on [here])https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk).

*Format the disk. You can use any file format that you need, but the most simple method is to format the entire disk with a single ext4 file system and no partition table. If you resize the zonal persistent disk later, you can resize the file system without having to modify disk partitions.*
`sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/[DEVICE_ID]`

Comment: @telcoM Thought so but wasn't certain. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me the line below added to  /etc/fstab did work (in Oracle cloud). You should change UID, you get correct uid by `sudo blkid`. After updating /etc/fstab update mounting by `sudo mount -a`

```
UID=86e62531-ad0b-4552-9df1-f14b73baf2a5 /data ext4 ro,noload,nofail 0 1
```